# WP_Filesystem usage within a block of code

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, forms, wp-filesystem

What i am trying to do is to have this function working within my plugin block of code without having it as plugin on it own.

My current and working solution outside wordpress is

**Save contents**

```
$KeepText="$name||$Phone||";
$dataHolder="keepdata.txt";
$file = fopen($dataHolder,"w");
if(fwrite($file, $KeepText)){echo "Data Saved Successfully !";}
else{echo "Error Occur !";}
fclose($file);
```

**Retrieve data**

```
$dataHolder="keepdata.txt";
$dataPool=file($dataHolder);
$TextPool=explode("||", (string)$dataPool[0]);

if ($dataPool) {
$ContactName=$TextPool[0];
$ContactPhone = $TextPool[1];
}
```

**Output**
//ContactName
//ContactPhone

The logic will perfectly print out all required data.

However doing the same thing within WordPress generate errors or not even echoing  out datas.

I have came across recommended solutions which suggested using the WP_Filesystem .
[From This Website](http://ottopress.com/2011/tutorial-using-the-wp_filesystem/)
I have tried it in which it work fine as a standalone Plugin . But that is not the solution I want.

What I will like to do is have the wp_filesystem like this without admin_menu().

```
function filesystem_init($form_url, $method, $context, $fields = null) {
    global $wp_filesystem;

    if (false === ($creds = request_filesystem_credentials($form_url, $method, false, $context, $fields))) {

    return false;
        }

        if (!WP_Filesystem($creds)) {
        request_filesystem_credentials($form_url, $method, true, $context);
        return false;
        }
        return true; 
    }
```

And later have the `function dataTosave(){}` like the below

```
function dataTosave($form_url){
    global $wp_filesystem;

    check_admin_referer('contact_form');

    $contactname = sanitize_text_field($_POST['contactname']); 
    $contactphone = sanitize_text_field($_POST['contactphone']); 

    $form_fields = array('contactname','contactphone'); 

    $method = ''; 
    $context = WP_PLUGIN_DIR . '/keepdata'; 

    $form_url = wp_nonce_url($form_url, 'contact_form'); 

    if(!filesystem_init($form_url, $method, $context, $form_fields))
        return false; 

    $target_dir = $wp_filesystem->find_folder($context);
    $target_file = trailingslashit($target_dir).'/keepdata.txt';


    $dataTosave=$contactname."||".$contactphone."||";
    if(!$wp_filesystem->put_contents($target_file, $dataTosave, FS_CHMOD_FILE)) 
        return new WP_Error('writing_error', 'Error when writing file');           

    return "Data Saved";
}
```

Once the form is post

```
 if(isset($_POST['contactform_submit'])){
dataTosave();
//new submission run the function
}

<form method="post" action="" >
<?php wp_nonce_field('contact_form'); ?>
    <label for="contactname">Contact Name</label><br>
    <input id="contactname" name="contactname" value="<?php echo $_POST['contactname']?>" require >
<label for="contactphone">Contact Phone</label><br>
    <input id="contactphone" name="contactphone" value="<?php echo $_POST['contactphone']?>" required >



<?php submit_button('Submit', 'primary', 'contactform_submit', true);?>

</form>
```

I have do it like this but no luck .Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading and writing to a file is going to be dicey. You are going to be fighting with file permissions if you save anywhere but the `wp-content/uploads` directory (and it looks like you want to save to the plugins directory). If you have sufficient control of the server, you may get this to work by editing permissions in the plugins directory, *but I wouldn't*. It introduces, potentially, security problems. At any rate, requiring that directory permissions be edited will make your code very non-portable.

1. You can save your file to `wp-content/uploads` but it may well
   accessible to snooping.
2. You can use `WP_Filesystem` but you will need to get
   `request_filesystem_credentials()` working most likely. I don't know
   what you mean by using it without `admin_menu()` but I am thinking
   you mean without the dialogue. [If I remember correctly, if you
   hardcode credentials in to `wp-config.php` you won't get the popup
   dialogue](https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#WordPress_Upgrade_Constants). You may be requiring users to edit files, which makes
   your code less portable.
3. The best option to me is to simply not try to juggle data into and
   out of a file. [Save your data as user meta](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_user_meta) in the database.

Comment: With your explanation I have change my mind to use Database instead of writing to file. However wp_usermeta structure will not fit into what I need to do so i will have to create table for this purpose. Thanks for your response

Comment: Why won't the usermeta table work? Your data does not look very complicated.

Comment: As you can see I need to add contact name and phone number . my idea is not for the user to register on wp registration page neither have any role to play on the site all they needs will be provides within the plugin scope and ends there.

Comment: If I am not asking you too much, can you produce block of code that can accomplish such task using wp_usermeta

Comment: Not if you are going to completely bypass user registration, which, by the way, I also consider a bad idea. However, you could save to the `$wpdb->options` table instead of the `$wpdb->usermeta` table.